# Should I Use SQL or XML?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I want to upgrade my site so that adding new projects or even entries to it is simple and quick. My original idea was to upgrade it to incorporate php and an sql database but i don't want to have to keep logging into MySQL every time I want to add a new project and I don't really want to spend lots of time on an admin section for my site so my second idea is to use php and XML to create a system where i can drag and drop folders via FTP and have my site discover each folder, create a div for each folder discovered and use the XML document and media within each folder to populate its DIV.

Basically should I stick to php and MySQL or would using XML be just as effective for my site.
my site is just a portfolio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the choice is between a database server which is optimized for storing and retrieving data, or manually parsing an XML file every time, go for a database.

Comment: Also, creating a small admin screen to add projects shouldn't take too much effort, does it?

Comment: Who needs an admin screen if one has phpmyadmin?

Comment: Perhaps he has more people who administer the projects on that site? People that you wouldn't trust to muck about in the database...

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the case, but true, if there's less technical people involved, phpmyadmin is a bad idea.

Comment: The case is that my primary focus is game design and programming, of which I would like to be spending most of my free time on when I am not at work, with web dev being a secondary focus. I figured maybe it would be quicker for me if I made a self updating website, where by all i need to do is drop the project media and xml document detailing the project into a folder and the site would take care of the rest etc. Dont want to have to spend too long on the site work, as like i say, i want to get on with my game dev etc.

Comment: You will probably be spending more time building the XML parsing and proper caching then you would adding a few dozen projects ;)

Comment: thanks for the input :D sticking with mysql it is then :D

Comment: You could also look at alternative RDBMSes too, such as sqlite, and see if it fits your needs better. MySQL is pretty good, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a few little back-end areas for a few little websites (less than 10 pages each) and in doing so learn't quite a bit from practical experience of using XML in the way you describe.

I think a lot of the 'suitability' - this is what you are asking - relates to how you plan to transform the data you store in xml into the website.

For example, i made a small blog for a wedding photography website that parses a small xml file and, on finding each blog element, injects the content from within this post into the page. If you are cunning and provide a default namespace of HTML/XHTML on a container element,  in my case, and so describe all the content below using normal HTML/XHTML tags, then you can simply inject all the childnodes of  into your HTML/XHTML page will just a few lines of PHP...and you can validate the XHTML/HTML you write in the XML document before production. This sort of activity is perfectly valid - it is a simple procedure of opening the file, reading the xml and injecting into the page.

Some MySQL people might find this a strange way of doing things, but i find for small sites it is useful and after a while you find yourself creating similar features quite easy - for example a list of customer testimonials.

Now, constructing some sort of back-end as you describe above to updating a blog post or small text snippet isolated to a single page is straightforward and for a small portfolio site i don't see any issue.

HOWEVER, as much as i like doing this sort of thing myself - as soon as the website gets beyond a few pages, it is difficult to manage.

The difficulty is - i think - to do with the fact that XML and Databases like MySQL belong it two separate activity domains and thus are 'built' for different purposes. What i mean by that is that XML is document-orientated format which we tend to use to describe a specific 'object' - often a document itself (e.g a webpage - HTML) according to a vocabulary. Databases models or express relationship between data - hence the term 'relational database'. This makes the latter much more useful for websites as it's easier to store and extract intelligent data that might be related / interesting to what a user is looking at. Think of an e-commerce website. If you used XML documents to contain product data it would be a lot trickier to, say, pull out related products than using MySQL, and it would also be a lot harder to manage - think of the 1000's of products.

The other factor in using XML documents of course is that as an XML document gets larger, depending on how you access the elements within, memory usage grows. This is particualy true of the DOM, however in PHP5 the XMLReader is quite low on memory consumption.

Anyway, in conclusion, for a portfolio site why not use XML (but ideally use XMLReader - or DOM if only a small XML document) but for a larger one, unfortunately MySQL or similar is the way to go.